# Do nothing on laptop close not available in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: laptop, lid

I'm running Ubuntu Studio, which is based on Ubuntu 19.04.  I want it to do nothing when I close the laptop lid.  I'm able to do this in Kubuntu 18.04 via the Power settings.  But I can't get this to work in Ubuntu 19.04.  I go to the XFCE Power Manager, and for laptop lid close I'm only offered three alternatives: Suspend, Switch Off Display, and Lock Screen, whether or not I'm on battery power.  How can I specify Do Nothing?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and this link: [How to Change Lid Close Action in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) helped:

In file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` change the line:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

To:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Either run: `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` or `reboot`.

In my case I had to reboot before this worked.

This still works on Ubuntu **19.04**